# Calling Fortran subroutine from Julia. Arrays work, but integers don't

Tags: fortran, julia, fortran90

I have this simple Fortran 90 program:

```
subroutine apc_wrapper(i, j, k)
implicit none

integer*8, intent(in) :: i, j
integer*8, intent(out) :: k
double precision t

k = i + js 
end subroutine
```

compiled as a shared library

```
gfortran -O2 -shared -fPIC apc_wrapper.f90 -o apc_wrapper.so
```

Now, I want to call this subroutine from Julia, with all integer arguments, like this

```
i = 2
j = 3
k = 0

ccall( (:apc_wrapper_, "./apc_wrapper.so"), Void, (Ptr{Int64}, Ptr{Int64}, Ptr{Int64}), &i, &j, &k)
```

But it won't work. `k` won't change its value and keep evaluating to 0.

But, if I do this

```
 i = 2
 j = 3
 kk = [0]

 ccall( (:apc_wrapper_, "./apc_wrapper.so"), Void, (Ptr{Int64}, Ptr{Int64}, Ptr{Int64}), &i, &j, kk)
```

That is, use an array to store the output, it works! After calling the subroutine, `kk` evaluates to

```
 1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 5
```

And I didn't change the Fortran code at all, it didn't even know it was dealing with an array, just a block of memory.

So, if Fortran is able to read blocks of memory (`i` and `j` were properly red) why isn't able to write into them?

I don't have any problem with this. Actually, I want to use an array as output but still, this behavior surprised me.

Comment: Untested hunch: instead of the shorthand `&k` syntax, you need to explicitly create `k = Ref(0)`.  Then access the current value of `k` with `k[]`.

Comment: Yes! I came to say that. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you sorted your problem out, but while we're looking at this it would be good to point out  integer*8 isn't, and has never been, standard Fortran, please learn about kinds - see e.g. stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: Oh, you are right, the good old `kind`. I guess one forgets all the nuances of a language when stops using it. I''ll add that, thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, Julia is a fast-paced developing language and it turns out that the `&variable` syntax is deprecated.
This would be the proper way to do this:

```
i = 2
j = 3
k = 0
i_ref = Ref{Int64}(i)
j_ref = Ref{Int64}(j)
k_ref = Ref{Int64}(k)

ccall( (:apc_wrapper_, "./apc_wrapper.so"), Void,
(Ref{Int64}, Ref{Int64}, Ref{Int64}),
i_ref, j_ref, k_ref)
```

and then `k_ref.x` will evaluate to `5`.

Comment: I find it insane that this is necessary to update a scalar in a `ccall` to Fortran when the official documentation claims `Julia has a "no boilerplate" philosophy`. Manually creating a `Ref` and fetching the value after the call is nothing but the worst sort of boilerplate in my book.